# How to set another name for similar records in model, for further binding with form fields in ext js?

Tags: javascript, forms, extjs

Have a project on ext js 6. I'm a newbie in it, but I have read a docs, experimented on it, but didn't understood anything. The point of trouble is: there is a form, which has binding to the model. 
Form fields:

```js
{
     xtype: 'checkboxfield',
     fieldLabel: 'Field1',
     bind: '{someField1}'
},
{
     xtype: 'textfield',
     fieldLabel: 'Field2',
     bind: '{someField2}'
}
```

Model fields:

```js
{
name: 'someField1',
type: 'boolean',
mapping: 'some_field_1'
},
{
name: 'someField2',
type: 'string',
mapping: 'some_field_2'
},
```

As I understand it, every field which has the model, transmitted to server. And this field described by "name" key.

But question is, what if I need, that in model would be few fields, with the same names? But form fields connected to model by name, and an interpreter will not understand which fields do I need..

So I need that model fields would have different names, but transmitted to server with the same name. Is there a possibility to do this?
Because there is a server response, and "mapping" grabs the model field and insert it into form input. But it doesn't work vise versa, and client sends value with "name" key. Help me to understand and solve this problem, please)

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "But question is, what if I need, that in model would be few fields, with the same names?"

Comment: I think he is saying that he needs to post the values over as an array, so he can say have 3 things being sent like favoriteNumbers = [1,3,5], but then in the model in ext have them set to favoriteNumber1, favoriteNumber2 etc.  If this is the case, you can try and set the values in the model using a convert function?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I mean that if model would have
{
name: 'someField1',
type: 'boolean',
mapping: 'some_field_1'
},
{
name: 'someField1',
type: 'boolean',
mapping: 'some_field_2'
},

Answer (score 0):

If you update the bind code on the view to look like this

```
bind: { 
   value : '{someField1}'
}
```

you can probably set the name then independent of the binding.

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to what's in the OP, since the `defaultBindProperty` of fields is `value`.

Comment: So you mean, that sending value to server would be different from "binding name"? If I pass the value?

Comment: try just setting the name of the field via the config, and use this binding provided above for the value and let me know what happens.